# GlSurfaceView Transparent Background Without Using GlSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

Tags: glsurfaceview

I have made a 3d object with **GlSurfaceView** and it shows black background.
When I use `GlSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true)` then this black background is gone but, issue is that the object comes on the top no another view or image show on front of it. I need to be remove this black background and image show on the front of it.